# GCC Segfaults When `decltype` Used in Nested Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, c++11

I created a macro that conveniently builds lambda functions using which I can iterate through tensor objects in a library that I wrote. However, nesting these macros seemed to cause GCC to undergo an internal segmentation fault. Upon expanding the compiler's preprocessor output and going through some trial and error, I discovered that cause seems to be the use of `decltype` in the parameter list of a nested lambda function declared in the method of a class or struct. Below follows a minimal example using the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class Iterator, class Func>
void for_each(const Iterator first, const Iterator last, Func func)
{
        for (Iterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
                func(*it);
        }
}

template <class T>
class helper
{
        typedef typename T::size_type type;
};

template <class T>
class helper<T&>
{
        typedef typename T::size_type type;
};

template <class T>
class helper<T*>
{
        typedef typename T::size_type type;
};      

struct bar
{
        struct foo
        {
                typedef int size_type;
        } foo_;

        void test()
        {
                int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                for_each(arr, arr + 3, [&](int i) {
                        /*
                        ** XXX: The "typename ... type" segfaults g++!
                        */
                        for_each(arr, arr + 3, [&](typename helper<decltype(foo_)>::type j) {

                        });
                });
        }
};

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

#### Compiler Output:

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x nested_lambda.cpp
nested_lambda.cpp: In lambda function:
nested_lambda.cpp:42:56: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccqYohFA.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
```

I initially opted to use `decltype` because an object is passed to a macro, and I need to extract the object's type. From the object's type, (`T`, `T&`, or `T*`), I'd use a traits class to pull `T::size_type.` `size_type` would then be the type of the lambda function parameters.

How can I circumvent this issue without having to use a typedef to declare the type of the lambda function parameter in advance? If you can think of some other solution that could easily be implemented in a macro (i.e. copied and pasted repeatedly in the parameter list of a lambda function), that would work too.

Comment: Have you, in fact, filed a full bug report as the compiler output requests?  Often one benefit of filing a bug report is that the compiler engineers who read it will make a suggestion on how to work around the problem.  It's difficult to know how to avoid it without knowing the compiler internals.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52014.

Comment: Why do you need typename at all here ? `helper<decltype(foo_)>::type` has no dependent types since you're not in a template.

Comment: My bad, it is indeed unnecessary; I typed the keyword by habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is currently being [addressed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52026), and I think that it should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

As a very rough workaround for those who may be experiencing similar issues, the best standard solution I could come up with involved having the macro declare a typedef in advance, concatenating GUID-like prefix (I personally recommend `_qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n_s0a02_`) and `__LINE__` to generate some warbled nonsense for the typedef name. With all luck, this name will not clash with any other definitions.

To ensure that the same `__LINE__` gets concatenated even when the warbled name is used for the lambda function parameter types, the warbled name will need to be generated by a macro that is initially passed a macro parameter, as in the code sample below.

```
#define _foo_GUID \
    _qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n_s0a02_

#define _foo_MANGLE_IMPL2(a, b) \
    a ## b

#define _foo_MANGLE_IMPL(a, b) \
    _foo_MANGLE_IMPL2(a, b)

#define _foo_MANGLE(a) \
    _foo_MANGLE_IMPL(_foo_GUID, a)
```

When passing `_foo_MANGLE(__LINE__)` as a macro parameter, please ensure that there is an extra level of indirection so that `_foo_MANGLE(__LINE__)` gets evaluated before it is used.

Comment: Names beginning with two underscores (or a single underscore followed by a capital letter) are illegal for use in user code, as they're reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer so that the macro is standard-conforming.

Comment: Hm? There are still `__GUID`, `__MANGLE_IMPL2`, `__MANGLE_IMPL`, and `__MANGLE` -- all of these are illegal. Also (I didn't mention earlier) any name beginning with an underscore in global scope is reserved as well, so `_qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n__s0a02__` is still a problem.

Comment: By name, I thought you only meant identifiers for declarations. I know of many libraries that declare macros beginning with two underscores. Anyway, I edited it again.

Comment: Unless those libraries are ones that come with your compiler then those libraries are also violating the standard.

Comment: As for `_qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n__s0a02__`, the intended use of the front-end macro that uses `_MANGLE` is in methods only, so `_qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n__s0a02__` should never be placed in global scope.

Comment: Fair enough, as long as it's not used to declare real symbols in global scope, since they'll begin with `_q`. (Also, again, names beginning with a single underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved regardless of scope, so `_GUID` etc. are still no-go.)

Comment: All names containing a double underscore *anywhere* are reserved, so `_qki_zbeu26_w92b27bqy_r62zf91j2n__s0a02__` is still a reserved identifier.

Comment: I've modified my answer again to be safe, but I have never before heard that a name containing a double underscore *anywhere* is reserved. Where is this stated in the ISO C++ standard?